# pulling all fullnames of contacts in group via GAS - loop issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script

Having difficulty pulling out an array of fullnames of my contacts.

```
function contact(){
  var emf = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('emf').getContacts(); // gets array of all GContacts in emf

  for(var i=0;i<emf.length;i++){
      var contactName = emf[i].getFullName();
      var fullnames[];
  }
}
```

So `emf[0].getFullName()+ emf[1].getFullName()+emf[2].getFullName() + ....` will get the names manually one by one. Can't figure out the loop.

Comment: can you include the data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a loop at all. Going through an array one by one, performing some operation, and putting the results in another array is exactly what the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for.

```
  var fullNames = emf.map(function(contact) {
     return contact.getFullName();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want each name in an array, you can do:

```
...

var fullnames = [];

for(var i=0;i<emf.length;i++){
      var contactName = emf[i].getFullName();
      fullnames.push(contactName);
  }
```

This will add each contact's full name to your array.